# Simulate Mouse Drag Programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse

I have a Windows Forms application with a control. The control consists of a chart panel with a canvas on which I paint. What I would like to do is to programmatically mouse drag the panel so that I have a specific distance between the right edge of the canvas and the last item painted on the canvas. I have tried two approaches. The both work in the sense that the panel is dragged as desired BUT I cannot seem to be able to get the precision of movement I desire. I coded a mouse simulator and have tried two approaches.

Approach 1:

```
 if(this.ChartControl.ChartPanel.CanFocus)
 {
      // ... Focus the chart panel to be adjusted.
      this.ChartControl.ChartPanel.Focus();

      // ... Move cursor to lastBarScreenCoordinates on the chart panel to be adjusted.
      Cursor.Position = new Point(lastBarScreenCoordinates.X, lastBarScreenCoordinates.Y);

      MouseSimulator.SetMouseDragThresholds();

      // ... Move chart panel to required position.
      MouseSimulator.LeftMouseButtonDown(lastBarScreenCoordinates.X, lastBarScreenCoordinates.Y);
      MouseSimulator.MouseMove(lastBarScreenCoordinates.X-positionShift,
           lastBarScreenCoordinates.Y);
      MouseSimulator.LeftMouseButtonUp(lastBarScreenCoordinates.X-positionShift,
           lastBarScreenCoordinates.Y);

      MouseSimulator.ResetMouseDragThresholds(_cx_default, _cy_default);

      // ... Redraw the chart panel.
      this.ChartControl.ChartPanel.Refresh();

      // ... Reset cursor to its starting position.
      Cursor.Position = new Point(startingCursorX, startingCursorY);
 }
```

Approach 2:

```
 if(this.ChartControl.ChartPanel.CanFocus)
 {
      // ... Focus the chart panel to be adjusted.
      this.ChartControl.ChartPanel.Focus();

      // ... Move cursor to lastBarScreenCoordinates on the chart panel to be adjusted.
      Cursor.Position = new Point(lastBarScreenCoordinates.X, lastBarScreenCoordinates.Y);

      MouseSimulator.SetMouseDragThresholds();

      // ... Move chart panel to required position.
      MouseSimulator.LeftMouseButtonDown(lastBarScreenCoordinates.X, lastBarScreenCoordinates.Y);
      Cursor.Position = new Point(lastBarScreenCoordinates.X-positionShift,
           lastBarScreenCoordinates.Y);
      WindowsCommunication.SendMessage(this.ChartControl.Handle, 0x200, IntPtr.Zero,IntPtr.Zero);
      MouseSimulator.LeftMouseButtonUp(lastBarScreenCoordinates.X-positionShift,
           lastBarScreenCoordinates.Y);

      MouseSimulator.ResetMouseDragThresholds(_cx_default, _cy_default);

      // ... Redraw the chart panel.
      this.ChartControl.ChartPanel.Refresh();

      // ... Reset cursor to its starting position.
      Cursor.Position = new Point(startingCursorX, startingCursorY);
 }
```

I am using SendInput for simulating mouse clicks. Here is sample left mouse button down code ...

```
 public static void LeftMouseButtonDown(int x, int y)
 {
      INPUT mouseInput = new INPUT();
      mouseInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
      mouseInput.mkhi.mi.dx = CalculateAbsoluteCoordinateX(x);
      mouseInput.mkhi.mi.dy = CalculateAbsoluteCoordinateY(y);
      mouseInput.mkhi.mi.mouseData = 0;
      mouseInput.mkhi.mi.time = 0;
      mouseInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
      SendInput(1, ref mouseInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));
 }
```

And I calculate normalized absolute coordinates for the mouse as follows ...

```
 private static int CalculateAbsoluteCoordinateX(int x)
 {
      return ((x * 65536) + GetSystemMetrics(SystemMetric.SM_CXSCREEN) - 1) /
           GetSystemMetrics(SystemMetric.SM_CXSCREEN);
 }
```

So here are the precision issues. If I use Approach 1 (mouse move), the measured distance between the last item painted and the right edge of the canvas is different from what I set in positionShift and the cursor position difference does not equal positionShift. I initially thought it was due to pointer ballistics issues so I tried using Approach 2. Approach 2 does give me precision in pointer positioning but I am still having difficulty in that the panel moves but the distance between the last bar painted and the right edge of the canvas does not equal the positionShift amount as it should. It always seems to be off. I have been working on this for a long time now and am at my wits end. I am not sure what is going on here. How to improve the precision in my canvas drag by simulated mouse drag?

Comment: What's the point of this?  Just draw on the canvas directly.

Comment: This is an add on to an existing application so I cannot control where the last element is drawn. I am trying to drag a panel precisely not draw on it.

Answer (score 0):

Well what you can do is this, First of all I believe the SendInput API allows for an AbsoluteValue flag so there is no need to calculate those values which may be the issue but most likely not.

Although I am curious as to why you are using a Mouse Drag opperation for this. It seems like all you want to do is reposition the canvas on every draw by some specified amount. if this is the case why not just set it explicitly on the canvas itself. Also it is unclear if you are using pure WinForms or WPF. The unclear bit being Canvas which I am fairly certain is only usable with WPF enabled windows.

That being said
WPF fix, 
Depending on the Object containing the canvas just set its margin appropriately for the situation, since I do not know the data you are working with I cant say much about that. But this is a relatively simple idea so let me know if that works, it should give you, at least close too, a pixel perfect alignment.

WinForms,
Just do the above for the "Canvas" object you were talking about, or use absolute coordinates of the object to move it around.

If you could supply a sample of what you were working on looked like roughly maybe we could have a better idea of what you mean.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In Approach 1, MouseMove, I do use the ABSOLUTE flag. I have found Approach 1 to be even less precise than Approach 2. I attributed this to pointer ballistic issues. Regarding the other items. This is Winforms not WPF. I already use absolute coordinates for the move in both approaches. The margin will not work because although I can reset it, it prevents drawing into the margin area which I need to do. I am intrigued by your suggestion to reposition the canvas. Can you suggest how I might be able to do that in WinForms? Thank you.